# How to force brackets on the same line even with comments

Tags: clang-format

If I run `clang-format` with only `BasedOnStyle: Google` on the following code

```cpp
int main() {
  if (1 < 2)  // This is a comment
              // I am a comment
  {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0
}
```

I get back the same code. Is it possible to instead force the opening bracket to be on the same line?

```cpp
int main() {
  if (1 < 2) {  // This is a comment
                // I am a comment
    return 1;
  }
  return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, clang-format won't do this. With only a few exceptions, clang-format only changes whitespace (exceptions include `FixNamespaceCommments`, `ReflowComments`, `SortIncludes`, and `SortUsingDeclarations`). Your change would require moving the opening bracket from before the comments to after the comments, so clang-format won't do it.